# Download a BLOB file from database

Tags: java, database, swing, download, jbutton

I need to create a `JButton` to download a BLOB file from oracle database.
This is my `JButton` code:

```
JButton btnsave = new JButton("Save");
btnsave.setBounds(478, 542, 120, 23);
getContentPane().add(btnsave);
btnsave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


}
});
```

This class is already connected to database, but here is part of my code:

```
Connection con;


String link="*******************************************";
       String u="user";
       String p="pw";
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       conn=DriverManager.getConnection(link,u,p);


Statement su=con.createStatement();
```

So how can i download a blob file with an `ActionListener` in my `JButton`? I also need to create another statement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code (but I can't try at the moment). `query` is the query, `index` the index column in the `SELECT` clausole, and `file` is the output file.

```
// take the result of the query
ResultSet rs = su.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()) { // for each row
   // take the blob
   Blob blob = rs.getBlob(index);
   BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream());
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
   // you can set the size of the buffer
   byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
   int r = 0;
   while((r = is.read(buffer))!=-1) {
      fos.write(buffer, 0, r);
   }
   fos.flush();
   fos.close();
   is.close();
   blob.free();
}
su.close();
```

Again, I can't try this code at the moment. Test it before be sure it works like you want.

Comment: How can i add this to an ActionListner?

Comment: You put the code in the `actioPerformed(ActionEvent)` implementation.

Comment: @Alberto thanks! it works! even if it's an old answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to perform long operations in ActionListener. Try this approach:

- Implement callback for notification that your blob has been loaded
- Implement thread which perform SQL operations(loading blob)
- Create ActionListener which starts thread from prev. step

Here is an example:

```
private JButton button = new JButton(new ClickListener());
private LoaderListener blobLoaderListener = new BlobLoaderListener();
private byte[] blob;
private Connection con; // connection code is ommited

private class ClickListener extends AbstractAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new SQLLoader(blobLoaderListener).start();
    }
}

private class SQLLoader extends Thread {
    private final LoaderListener listener;

    public SQLLoader(LoaderListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] blob = null;
        try {
            // create another statement here 
            Statement su = con.createStatement();

            // perform you SQL query, get your 'blog'
            // once you have done, notify listener
            listener.onLoad(blob);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            listener.onError();
        }
    }
}

private interface LoaderListener {
    void onLoad(byte[] blob);

    void onError();
}

private class BlobLoaderListener implements LoaderListener {
    @Override
    public void onLoad(byte[] blob) {
        BlobLoader.this.blob = blob;
        // notify UI about changes
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        // TODO 
    }
}
```